# ubuntu unattended-upgrades don't start

Tags: apt

ubuntu 20.04 unattended-upgrades don't start.
They should be started by the cronjob `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat`.

The first part of the script prevents that:

```
# Systemd systems use a systemd timer unit which is preferable to
# run. We want to randomize the apt update and unattended-upgrade
# runs as much as possible to avoid hitting the mirrors all at the
# same time. The systemd time is better at this than the fixed
# cron.daily time

if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
exit 0
fi
```

My question is: how do I convince the script to pass the if condition. I understand the comment but it quite abstract.

There is no package deployed that contains this directory.

```
# dpkg -S /run/systemd/system
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /run/systemd/system
```

And please don't write me simply to delete this directory. It contains files.

```
# ls -la /run/systemd/system 
total 4 
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  80 May  1 16:28 . 
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 540 May  1 16:28 .. 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 299 May  1 16:28 netplan-ovs-cleanup.service 
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  60 May  1 16:28 systemd-networkd.service.wants `
```

I expect the unattended-upgrades to start with the cronjob.
I ran the script in debug with set -x
I ran the finally referenced command in the script exec `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`. This work fine and starts the unattended-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If your system uses systemd (which is what the condition checks for), the unattended upgrades are not run from cron, but from a systemd timer.

Look for /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily* .